# Add "Delete" button to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, button

I want to add a custom delete button to my UITableViewCell, not the standard swipe to delete. All I need it to do is to delete the cell. I'm using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController.

Does anyone know an action I could use? I'd like it to be an IBAction so I can link it to a button on the cell.

EDIT: I want to clarify that I understand how to put the button on the cell, but I need help with the action to delete the cell. Thanks!

EDIT 2: Here's the editingStyle code. I don't want to have to use the stock swipe-to-delete though, but use a custom button. Does anyone have an idea how to turn this code into an action that could be hooked up to a button?

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    // Delete the task 
    Task *taskToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", taskToDelete.name);
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:taskToDelete];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    // Delete the row 
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [self performFetch];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: [[cell contentView] addSubview:deleteButton]; // Where loginButton is a pointer that points to instance of UIButton. You can also add target action to that button.

Comment: I know how to add the button, but not how to create an action to delete the cell.

Comment: Delete that row and update the TableView

Answer (score 1):

Delete the corresponding row from your model and then tell the table view to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.